# interesting network or git problem

Tags: git, ssh, commit

I have a setup my own git repository with gitosis on dedicated debian server. The server is visible via port 22 from outside (the port 22 is forwarded from my router to my git server). On the local network the git repository works perfectly. The problem happens once I try to do "git clone.." from remote server. So once I do "git clone.." from remote I am getting git clone hung after cloning around 20-30% of the repository (small around 2MB) and I think this is the random percentage. I can do scp to and from the git server without any problems. Also as I mentioned the git clone, push, etc works perfectly within my internal network.
Any idea how to debug this problem?
thanks

Comment: i think is is related to my ISP as scp (downloading from my server) does not work.
thanks

Comment: it looks like scp stalling problem

Answer (score 1):

Stalling TCP connections are often caused by MTU problems. Google that and see if there are adjustments you need to do in your router to get it to play along better with whatever your ISP is doing. Besides that, this would be better asked on serverfault.com.

Comment: indeed it is stalling TCP connection problem. Once I change MTU to 1500 scp works perfectly but then some of the www pages loads extremely slow - even local ones. If I set MTU on my ADSL router to 1492 all www pages loads fast but i am getting problem with scp. Ok I will post this thing on serverfault.com. cheers